# After finishing the main quests, is Dishonored an open-world game?

Tags: dishonored

I want to buy Dishonored, but can I play open-world after finishing the main quest?
I mean playing free-roam, killing anyone like in Assassin's Creed.

Comment: Free as in without paying? What does this have to do with not killing anyone? You can only play the first tutorial level in the demo, so not sure what you are asking here. I realise English might be your first language, but at least make an effort in organising your idea in coherent sentences.

Comment: @deutschZuid Woah, I think you're being overly harsh here. They meant free as in able to explore and do whatever you want.

Comment: @deutschZuid He's talking about open worlds. Not "free" as "without paying", but "without in-game restrictions". You know... open world?

Comment: That's why I asked. I had no idea. Logically, one understands free as without paying after clauses like "I want to buy the game, but". Sorry can't agree with you two here.

Comment: @deutschZuid In its original form I can agree that the question was ambiguous. It's always fine to ask for clarification, but it's better to suggest improvements without criticism. We don't want to scare off all our new users :)

Comment: Perhaps @handson777 meant 'free-roam' (another term for 'open world') by 'free' in the first version of his post.

Answer (score 6):

Dishonored isn't an open world game. It is a linear series of missions set in large, fairly open areas which provide freedom to reach your objectives in a number of ways. This includes stealthy, entirely non-lethal approaches as well as wanton slaughter.

You can, however, replay any missions you have already finished. So you could play the game 'properly' the first time round (however you want to define that) to get the ending that you want, and then go back and replay each mission and kill everyone in your path.